# What is (D/NSD: curPkgName is not in list)?

Tags: android, logcat

I am working on new project when I enter to RegisterActivity the logCat printing

```
11-07 20:12:09.305 26674-26674/com.rosheta D/NSD: curPkgName is not in list
```

too much and not stop printing it.
what is this? is this is an error? could this lot of logs printing reduce the performance of app?

here is my RegisterActivity

```
package com.rosheta.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.rosheta.R;
import com.rosheta.api.Api;
import com.rosheta.api.ApiHelper;
import com.rosheta.api.response.UsernameResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
* Created by Tefa on 07/11/2016.
*/

public class Reg extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText fName, lName, username, email, password, confirmPassword, phone;
Button signUp;
TextView login;
AppCompatImageButton checkUsername;
Api api;
private static final String TAG = Reg.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    initializeViewItems();
}

private void initializeViewItems() {
    fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_firstName);
    lName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_lastName);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_username);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_password);
    confirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_confirm_password);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act_register_et_phone);
    signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act_register_b_signup);
    signUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.act_register_tv_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    checkUsername = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.act_register_ib_check_username);
    checkUsername.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.act_register_b_signup:
            attemptLogin();
            break;
        case R.id.act_register_ib_check_username:
            String inputUsername = username.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputUsername)) {
                username.setError("Username can not be blank");
                return;
            } else {
                checkUsernameValidity(inputUsername);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void checkUsernameValidity(String inputUsername) {
    Log.d(TAG,"checkUsernameValidity");
    try {
        ApiHelper.base_url = getString(R.string.base_url);
        api = ApiHelper.getClient().create(Api.class);
        api.checkUsername(inputUsername).enqueue(new Callback<UsernameResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UsernameResponse> call, Response<UsernameResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response = 200");
                    UsernameResponse uResponse = response.body();
                    if (uResponse.getCode() == 20) {
                        checkUsername.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_accepted_username);
                    } else if (uResponse.getCode() == 3) {
                        checkUsername.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_invalid_username);
                        username.setError(uResponse.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "response != 200");
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.message())) {
                        Log.e(TAG, response.message());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UsernameResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fail");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Exceptio");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void attemptLogin() {
    String firstName = fName.getText().toString();
    String lastName = lName.getText().toString();
    String inputUsername = username.getText().toString();
    String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
    String inputPass = password.getText().toString();
    String inputCPass = confirmPassword.getText().toString();
    String inputPhone = phone.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)) {
        fName.setError("First name can not be blank");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)) {
        lName.setError("Last name can not be blank");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputUsername)) {
        username.setError("Email can not be blank");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputEmail)) {
        email.setError("Email can not be blank");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputPass)) {
        password.setError("Password can not be blank");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputCPass)) {
        confirmPassword.setError("Please confirm your password");
        return;
    }
    if (inputPass.equals(inputCPass)) {
        password.setError("Passwords don't match");
        return;
    }
    //TODO handle phone number
    //TODO register request
}
}
```

and activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_register"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rosheta.activities.RegisterActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/act_register_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_names_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/act_register_et_firstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:hint="First name"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/act_register_et_lastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:hint="Last name"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/act_register_et_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/act_register_et_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/act_register_ib_check_username"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_username"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/act_register_et_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/act_register_et_confirm_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/act_register_et_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="Phone number"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/act_register_b_signup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Sign up" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_have_account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/have_account_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/act_register_tv_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_have_account"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_have_account"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_have_account"
                android:text="login"
                tools:textColor="?android:attr/textColorLink" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[**update**]
I found a way to filter this Log from spamming my logcat
in top right corner of logcat select  **Edit Filter Configuration** 
1-in **filter name** write your app name 
2-in **package name** write your app_package_name 
3-in (**Log message** write ^((?!(?:THE_TAG_YOU_NEED_TO_IGNORE)).)*$ or **Log tag** write  ^((?!(?:THE_TAG_YOU_NEED_TO_IGNORE)).)*$ )

Comment: When log is printing? After starting activity or some click event?

Comment: thank for reply @Divyesh , it's printing when the activity starts immediately

Comment: Huawei phone using for testing?

Comment: yes
Huawei Y6II

Comment: Then it is not bug in your code. Huawei phones shows this log and they have not fixed it. So ignore it.

Comment: @Divyesh
Sorry for late, I think you are right I tried Genymotion now and it's not printing this log.
thanks, and please put your comment as an answer to accept it.

Comment: here is a regex command that will remove all unnecessary log in android monitor. Just select Regex and paste it in your textfield. 
^(?!.*(NSD|IInputConnectionWrapper|InputMethodManager|LAN|Choreographer|HwSecImmHelper|AudioManager|OpenGLRenderer|HwWidgetFactory|HwPolicyFactory|Firebase|art|KeyEvent|HAL|HwCust|ActivityThread|DynamiteModule|MultiDex|FA|System|CubicBezierInterpolator)).*$

Comment: thanks for the regex!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Then it is not bug in your code. Huawei phones shows this log and they have not fixed it. So ignore it.

Comment: do yo know what is the reason of this Log?
 because it's very annoying, it's confusing me when debugging my app.
it's not appearing in all app I work on,just one.

Comment: Just filter this error log in logcat, so it don't bother you anymore.

Comment: I looked in filter configurations there is no option for hiding or prevent some logs

Comment: I don't know about that, but there must be way to hide log.

Comment: Use a Regex filter to filter the output of your logcat: `^(?!.*(NSD)).*$`. Add any other tags you whish to hide: `^(?!.*(NSD|CubicBezierInterpolator)).*$`

Comment: Select the text and right click, choose `Fold lines like this`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me this might be related to the Theme Creator tool nsd.solutions.huaweithemecreator (https://www.apk-s.com/nsd.solutions.huaweithemecreator/), e.g., the UI is changing and the theme creator is checking if a custom theme should be applied given the package name.